# React Native: SDK directory does not exist

Tags: android, android-sdk, reactjs, sdk

Пытаюсь запустить дефолтный проект. Поначалу была ошибка:

> SDK location not found

На английском StackOverFlow [сказали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed):

> Go to the android/ directory of your react-native project
>   Create a file called local.properties with this line:
>   sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk

Я создал этот файл, записал туда путь к директории sdk:

> sdk.dir = /Users/Sketc_000/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1

Теперь выдаёт это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть, он использует записанный мной адрес, но почему-то приклеивает к нему вначале адрес папки с проектом. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы указали относительный путь.

Пропишите полный, от корня диска. Примерно так:

```
sdk.dir = C://Users/Sketc_000/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1
```